# Using plot.ly in R, is there a way to extract the interpolated data of a mesh3d plot?

Tags: r, plotly

I have a data set of Cartesian coordinates on a field and would like to map any given point to the mesh created using that data set.

```
plot_ly() %>%
   add_trace(data = sawgrass17green, 
        x=~previous_x, y=~previous_y, z=~previous_z, 
        type="mesh3d", intensity=~previous_z) %>%
   layout(scene = list(aspectmode='data'))
```

[3d mesh created by this code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1wFE.png)

[image]

I have tried using interpp to no avail - it creates strange artifacts in the data leading to outlying data points that aren't supported by the actual data. I'm probably making some mistakes in the implementation, but that's a separate question for another time.

The plot shown is the ideal - is there an underlying (accessible) interpolated data set creating the mesh, or is it purely a point to point visual interpolation?